# Get ajax response inside dataTable()

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my existing code for pagination here I am getting error as `roleList` is not defined.
I don't know how to use ajax response inside of `dataTable()`.What I did wrong?
I got struck with this part for last 3 days,however I searched for a solution for long time,but couldn't fine one.

```
function empRoles() {debugger
    table = $('#mydata').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "type": 'POST',
            "dataType": 'json',
            "url": '/Admin/getRolesList',
            "dataSrc": function (response) {
                var roleList = response;
                console.log(roleList)
            },
            "data": {
                "json": JSON.stringify(roleList)
            }

        },
        "columns": [{
            "data": "sNo"
        }, { 
            "data": "roleName",
            "className": "roleName"
        }, {
            "data": "roleName",
            "render": (data, type, row, meta) => `
                <button class="btn edit btn-info" id="edit${row.sNo}">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    Edit
                </button>
                <button class="btn update btn-success" id="update${row.sNo}">
                    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
                    Update
                </button>
                <button class="btn dlt btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm" id="delete${row.sNo}">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                    Delete
                </button>
            `
            ,
            "sortable": false
        }],
        "createdRow": (row, data, dataIndex) => {
            $(row).attr("id", "row" + data.sNo);
            $('td:eq(1)', row).attr("id", "name" + data.sNo);
        }
    });
}
```

Any advice please..

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly understanding the problem, I believe the simplest solution would be to simply initialize the `roleList` variable outside of the options.

```
function empRoles() {
    var roleList = []; // or whatever the initial data value should be
    var table = $('#mydata').DataTable({ 
    // ...
       "dataSrc": function (response) {
            roleList = response;
            console.log(roleList)
        },
        "data": {
            "json": JSON.stringify(roleList)
        }
    // ...
```

Comment: If I add  var `roleList = [];` means its showing error as`()DataTable` is not a function.

Comment: Well, the good news is `roleList` is defined! Did you have DataTable working before running into the current issue? Maybe double check you have required [the source](https://datatables.net/download/index)?

Comment: Yes I have added these 3 sources `dataTables.bootstrap.min.css` , `jquery.dataTables.min.js` , `dataTables.bootstrap.min.js` And one more thing I tried this same code without `ajax()` and I am getting the correct output.

Comment: Interesting. What's the exact error message you get when you include the ajax option?

Comment: Yup.When I use this code to get table data I am getting no errors https://jsfiddle.net/qmc4hjto/. When I use this method am getting error as `roleList` is not defined https://jsfiddle.net/ydoefthm/.Can you please teach me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The part of code

```
"data": {
            "json": JSON.stringify(roleList)
        }
```

is executed before

```
"dataSrc": function (response) {
            roleList = response;
            console.log(roleList)
        }
```

Therefore, the variable roleList is not available for ajax.data.

You can validate this by putting break points on your browser.

Here you are basically trying to access the input variable and pass it back to the server. The same can be achieved by own custom ajax section using functions as mentioned in this link -

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax